# Is setInterval() bad for performance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I am making a website which has a lot of JavaScript. Will use of setInterval() hurt the performance of my website?

Comment: What kind of performance are you interested in?

Comment: setInterval(function(){


// some script here


}, 1)

Comment: You might be interested in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648557/javascript-setinterval-behaviour-with-0-milliseconds). The browser sets a minimum that setInterval can run at (apparently around 10ms.)

Comment: It depends on the context...and that makes your question in its current state hard to answer...

Comment: Running something once a millisecond is probably going to hurt performance, and you aren't guaranteed to actually have it run every millisecond anyway. Best to describe why you want to use `setInterval`.

Comment: If it is not good to set 1 millisecond, whats the solution?

Comment: @Enve — The depends on what the *problem* is. "I want to do *something* every millisecond" is too vague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends what for you're using it and how. It can be really helpful if you want to do things asynchronously.

(would be really nice to see some code - then I would be able to say something more)