# JQuery countdown timer with milliseconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very basic lightweight function that counts down from 30 seconds. I have been trying to add milliseconds to it but I can't seem to get it to work correctly.

```
var count = 30;
var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second

function timer() {
    if (count <= 0) {
        clearInterval(counter);
        return;
    }
    count = count - 1;
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = count + " secs"; // watch for spelling
}
```

Comment: What do you mean you're trying to add milliseconds?

Comment: Four upvotes for this? I wonder what's going on.

Comment: What you've posted seems to be working: http://jsfiddle.net/t2Z2u/

Comment: @Faust it works but does not display 'milliseconds' just full seconds. I would like it to display both, similar to a stop watch.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi This is trickier than it sounds, no solution as of yet. That's probably why the up votes. I think there will be a lot of interest in the chosen solution (without over complicating it with bloat and libraries)

Comment: Also, you accepted an answer which gives you *hundreds* of a second, not *milli* seconds... \*bitter\*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try it [this way](http://jsfiddle.net/y6BZV/). Stopwatches only count hundredths of seconds anyway.

```
var count = 3000;

var counter = setInterval(timer, 10); //10 will  run it every 100th of a second

function timer()
{
    if (count <= 0)
    {
        clearInterval(counter);
        return;
     }
     count--;
     document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=count /100+ " secs"; 
}
```

[Just for better formatting and testing](http://jsfiddle.net/ydCq3/):

**HTML**

```
<span id="timer"></span>

<button id="start">start</button>
<button id="stop">stop</button>
<button id="reset">reset</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
var initial = 30000;
var count = initial;
var counter; //10 will  run it every 100th of a second

function timer() {
    if (count <= 0) {
        clearInterval(counter);
        return;
    }
    count--;
    displayCount(count);
}

function displayCount(count) {
    var res = count / 100;
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = res.toPrecision(count.toString().length) + " secs";
}

$('#start').on('click', function () {
    clearInterval(counter);
    counter = setInterval(timer, 10);
});

$('#stop').on('click', function () {
    clearInterval(counter);
});

$('#reset').on('click', function () {
    clearInterval(counter);
    count = initial;
    displayCount(count);
});

displayCount(initial);
```

**EDIT:**

The original question was trying to figure out how to make a display like a stopwatch, and I know very few that actually count milliseconds. That being said, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2cufprgL/1/) is a possible solution to do that. It relies on updating as fast as possible, and getting the difference between our last update and our current one to remain accurate.

```
var initial = 300000;
var count = initial;
var counter; //10 will  run it every 100th of a second
var initialMillis;

function timer() {
    if (count <= 0) {
        clearInterval(counter);
        return;
    }
    var current = Date.now();

    count = count - (current - initialMillis);
    initialMillis = current;
    displayCount(count);
}

function displayCount(count) {
    var res = count / 1000;
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = res.toPrecision(count.toString().length) + " secs";
}

$('#start').on('click', function () {
    clearInterval(counter);
    initialMillis = Date.now();
    counter = setInterval(timer, 1);
});

$('#stop').on('click', function () {
    clearInterval(counter);
});

$('#reset').on('click', function () {
    clearInterval(counter);
    count = initial;
    displayCount(count);
});

displayCount(initial);
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the browser can't possibly handle *manipulating the DOM* every millisecond. For this reason, lots of browsers actually set a minimum value for intervals - and the W3C suggest a minimum of 4ms [(source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648557/setinterval-behaviour-with-0-milliseconds-in-javascript). We can use this information to create a [*throttled* approach](http://jsfiddle.net/ianclark001/t5Eqe/) which runs as quickly as possible.

```
// We actually only run our method every x millisecs, due to browser constraints
var THROTTLE_AMOUNT = 4;

countdown(30);

function countdown(secs) {
    var milli = secs * (1000);
    var counter = setInterval(function() {
        if(milli <= 0) {
            clearInterval(counter);
            return
        }
        milli -= THROTTLE_AMOUNT;
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = milli + " millisecs"; // watch for spelling
    }, THROTTLE_AMOUNT);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but The seconds are running too slow. I has a similar issue when trying to resolve this - YOU EXAMPLE DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/x8dSP/2791/

Comment: Updated, I did mention in my question that it wouldn't work and why. please try now!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. If you're targeting modern browsers, you may have access to the `Performance` API, which gives high resolution timestamps instead of normal timestamps.

An improved solution would use `requestAnimationFrame()`. Updating the DOM every millisecond, even if possible with setTimeout(), is a waste of resources, as the browser will only refresh the screen, typically, 60 times in a second (every 16.6 ms). Updating the clock two times or more in that interval would be useless, and the user will only see the last value.

```
function now() {
    return window.performance ? window.performance.now() : Date.now();
}

var count = 30000;
var delay = 20; //20 ms. This will be only indicative. There's no guarantee the browswer will call the function after exactly this time

var initTick = 0;
var timerElement = document.getElementById("timer");
function tick() {
   var remaining = (count - (now() - initTick)) / 1000;  
   console.log(remaining);
   remaining = remaining >= 0 ? remaining : 0;
   var secs = remaining.toFixed(2);
   timerElement.innerHTML = secs + " secs";
   if (remaining) setTimeout(tick, delay);
}

initTick = now();
console.log(now());
setTimeout(tick, delay);
```

[JSFIDDLE.](http://jsfiddle.net/BEc8z/)

Answer (score 0):

```
  This may help you:

    var count = 30;
    var count1 = 60;
        //1000 will  run it every 1 second
        var counter1;
        var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

        function timer1() {
            if (count1 <= 0 && count < 1) {
                clearInterval(counter1);
                return;
            } else {
                if (count1 <= 0 && count > 0)
                    count1 = 60;
                else
                    count1 = count1 - 1;
                //var counter=setInterval(timer, 1000);
            }
            document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = count + "." + count1 + " secs"; // watch for spelling
        }
        function timer() {
            if (count <= 0) {
                clearInterval(counter);
                return;
            }
            else {
                counter1 = setInterval(timer1, 10);
            }
            count = count - 1;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Previous responses, I've derived a vanilla javascript, object oriented approach.

I've also created a github repo in case anyone wants to improve it.

https://github.com/denodster/JSTimer

```
function Timer(element){
    var interval;
    var milliseconds = 0;
    var self = this;

    function printValue(){
        var seconds = Math.round(milliseconds/10)/100;
        $(element).empty();
        $(element).text(seconds);
    }

    this.start = function(seconds, countdown){
        if(interval){//if an interval exists clear it first
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
        if(seconds) {//if seconds are passed in reset the milliseconds
            milliseconds = milliseconds + (seconds * 1000);
        }
        interval = setInterval(function(){
            if(countdown) {
                if (milliseconds >= 0) {
                    milliseconds -= 10;
                    printValue();
                } else {
                    self.stop();
                }
            } else {
                milliseconds += 10;
                printValue();
            }
        }, 10);
    };

    this.stop = function(){
        clearInterval(interval);
    };

    this.reset = function(){
        milliseconds = 0;
        printValue();
    };

    this.getValue = function(){
        return milliseconds/1000;
    };
}
```

Example:

```
<span id="counter"></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
//count down to zero from 10 seconds
var counter = document.getElementById('counter');
var timer = new Timer(counter);
timer.start(10, true);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old but I thought I should share my answer maybe it will help someone. This script counts the current date/time with milliseconds, minutes, seconds, month, day, year, and suffix, it is easy to modify, you can modify it to countdown if you need to

```js
    function showRemaining() {
    var currentDate = new Date(); //'11/23/2016 12:00 AM'
    var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1
    var day = currentDate.getDate()
    var year = currentDate.getFullYear()
    var currentTime = new Date()
    var hours = currentTime.getHours()
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
    var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
    //var milliseconds = currentTime.getMilliseconds().toString().slice(0, 3); //+ 999; //* 111
    var milliseconds = (currentTime.getMilliseconds()/.11).toFixed(0)
    //var milliseconds = currentTime * 3
    var timer;


    if (minutes < 10)
    minutes = "0" + minutes
    
    var suffix = "AM";
    if (hours >= 12) {
    suffix = "PM";
    hours = hours - 12;
    }
    if (hours === 0) {
    hours = 12;
    }
      
      if (seconds < 10)
        seconds = "0" + seconds
        
        if (seconds >= 60) {
          seconds = seconds - 60;
        }
      if (seconds === 60) {
        seconds = 60;
      }
      
      if (hours < 10)
        hours = "0" + hours
        
        if (hours >= 12) {
          hours = hours - 12;
        }
      if (hours === 12) {
        hours = 12;
      }
      
      if (milliseconds < 1000)
        milliseconds = "0000";// + milliseconds
        
        if (milliseconds >= 1000) {
          milliseconds = milliseconds - 100; //was 1000
        }
      if (milliseconds === 1000) {
        milliseconds = 1000;
      }
      
    var now = new Date();
    var distance = currentDate - now;
    if (distance < 0) {
    return;
    }
    
      /*var days = Math.floor(distance / day);
      var hours = Math.floor((distance % day) / hour);
      var minutes = Math.floor((distance % hours) / minute);
      var seconds = Math.floor((distance % minutes) / second);
      //var milliseconds = Math.floor(distance % _second) / _millisecond;*/
      
      document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = month + '/'; // months
      document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += day + '/'; // days
      document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += year + '<br>'; // year
      document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += hours + ' : '; // hrs
      document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += minutes + ' : '; // mins
      document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += seconds + ' : '; // secs
      document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += milliseconds + ' '; // milliseconds
      document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += '<b>' + suffix + '</b>'; // suffix

    }
      timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="countdown"></p>
</body>
</html>
```