# JavaScript setInteral() Performance

Tags: javascript, performance, setinterval

I was working on a project with JavaScript and I was wondering if I used `setInterval()` and set it to run each millisecond, would that cause performance issues? Would calling the function whenever needed be better performance wise? Or `setInterval()` doesn't affect the performance?

Comment: Browsers won't run it that fast anyway. Usually the shortest interval possible is around 15 or 16ms.

Comment: Depends on how expensive the callback is.

Comment: See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648557/setinterval-behaviour-with-0-milliseconds-in-javascript) SO question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you do setInterval , your function will be added to the stack each x ms. That doesn't mean that it will be executed each x ms. Indeed the stack may not be empty at the moment the function is added to it. So you will run your function with a period which is at least x ms (no precision guaranteed!). That's the only performance issue I know about setInterval 
Hope that helped!