# TimerObservable(0, 1) doesn't return milliseconds

Tags: rxjs

Why `TimerObservable.create(0, 1).subscribe(t => { console.log('ms', t) })` doesn't return milliseconds but something slower ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that browsers have a minimum value for the interval (which is usually 4ms). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648557/setinterval-behaviour-with-0-milliseconds-in-javascript) seems to be related. Also [see this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Notes) in the **Notes** section under ***Reasons for delays longer than specified***